# measure similarity between two distributions of a discrete variable

Tags: r

With a `df` below, I need to compute the similarity between the distributions of variable `metric` across the two `team` groups `tm1` and `tm2` on a per `locid` basis

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(
    locid = sample(c(1111,1122,1133), 20, replace=TRUE),
    day = sample(c(1:3), 20, replace=TRUE),
    hour = sample(c(1:4), 20, replace=TRUE),
    team = sample(c("tm1", "tm2", "tm3"), 20, replace=TRUE),
    metric = sample(1:5, 20, replace=TRUE )
)
```

Comment: What is the measure of similarity? Try `aggregate(metroc ~ locid + team, ...)`.

Comment: You could use a Chi-squared test of independence, see for instance http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76898/test-whether-two-multinomial-samples-come-from-the-same-distribution